# Reflection planes by Householder transform

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let we have two intersecting 2-dimentional planes in $\mathbb{R}^n$. First one contains linearly independent vectors $a$ and $b$, and the second one contains linearly independent vectors $u$ and $v$. If it is important let denote vector that lies in the intersection of planes as $s$. I need to set the Householder transform that maps first plane to the second. It is not necessary to map $a$ to $u$ or $b$ to $v$, I only need to represent the rotation around the vector $s$ that maps first plane to the second.

My idea is to compute the bisector plane between given planes and than just reflect over this bisector plane. But I can not write explicit formulas for such transform. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Begin by computing orthonormal bases for each of the planes using $s$.  I will assume that neither $a$ nor $u$ are a multiple of $s$.

$\{s,a\}$ is basis for the first plane.  Compute
$$
a^{\perp} = a - \frac{s^Ta}{s^Ts}s, \qquad w_1 = \frac{a^{\perp}}{\|a^{\perp}\|}\\
u^{\perp} = u - \frac{s^Tu}{s^Ts}s, \qquad w_2 = \frac{u^{\perp}}{\|u^{\perp}\|}
$$
Now, if $\hat s = \frac{s}{\|s\|}$, then $\{\hat s, w_1\}$ is an orthonormal basis for the first plane and $\{\hat s, w_2\}$ is an orthonormal basis for the second.

It suffices to find the Householder transformation which maps $w_1$ to $w_2$ (as in the answer to your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1903312/rotation-by-householder-matrices)).

Comment: Note that "reflecting over a $2$-dimensional plane" yields a Householder reflection in $3$ dimensions, but fails to do so in $n$-dimensional space.

Comment: It seems that it works even is $n$-dementional space. Anyway $\hat s$ is orthogonal to $w_1 - w_2$ than it stays on place, but $a$ maps to $u$. Great thanks!

Comment: Note: we can only say that $a$ maps to $u$ if these vectors are orthogonal to $s$ and of the same length.

Answer (score 1):

- Take for $c$ any vector orthogonal to $P_1$ and normalize it $c'=c/\|c\|.$
- Take for $w$ any vector orthogonal to $P_2$ and normalize it $w'=w/\|w\|.$

How is it possible ?

- if $n=3$ take $c=a \times b$ and $w=u \times v$.
- if $n>3$, we do the same, but we use a recipe given in remark below.

(Thanks to @Omnomnomnom who has made the remark that cross product, as such, does not exist in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n>3$).

The next step is to compute $V=w'-u'$, normalized as $V'=V/\|V\|$, which is a (unit) vector orthogonal to the bissector plane. Now we are able to use the classical formula for symmetry matrix $S$ with respect to a plane having unit normal vector $V'$:

$S=I-2V'V'^T$ where $I$ is the identity matrix.

For example, if $n=2$, let $V'=\binom{a}{b}$ ; then $$S=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}-2\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a&b\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1-2a^2&-2ab\\-2ab&1-2b^2\end{pmatrix}.$$

Remark: Being given 2 vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, how can we obtain a vector that is orthogonal to both ? It suffices to take the first 3 coordinates of $a$ and $b$, compute their cross product in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then fill in the $(n-3)$ remaining coordinates with zeros.

Comment: Cross-products don't work in $n$-dimensional space

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You are completely right. I am going to correct it.