# QR factorization using Householder Reflector

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods

For a 3 by 2 matrix, I want to find the QR factorization using Householder Reflector. For example, The first column of A is $(2, 1, 2)$ and the second column of A is $(1, -1, 1)$. Let $H_1$ be $I-2vv^T/(v^Tv)$, I found that the three rows of $H_1A$ are $(3,1), (0,-1),(0,1)$, which suggests that x bar is equal to $(-1,1)$. Now in order to find $H_2$, I need v bar, but to find v bar, I need w bar. Can someone help what is the w bar here? $(v=w-x)$

Comment: I am using $H_1H_2R$?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1903312/378968

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in the right direction except that you have not defined your notation and hence difficult to understand.
$$
 A = \left[ \begin{array}{rr}
2 & 1 \\
1 & -1 \\
2 & 1
\end{array}
\right].
$$After the first step, we get
$$
H_1 A = \left[ \begin{array}{rr}
3 & 1 \\
0 & -1 \\
0& 1
\end{array}
\right].
$$
Now, ignore the first row and the column of the matrix $H_1A$ before we apply a Householder reflector to the remainder of the matrix. The important part of $H_1A$ is at the bottom right.
$$
H_1A = \left[ \begin{array}{r|r}
x & x \\
\hline
0 & -1 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right].
$$
We apply the Householder reflector $H_2$ to the last two rows of $H_1A$ to get
$$
 \left[ \begin{array}{r|r}
x & x \\
\hline
0 & \sqrt{2} \\
0 & 0
\end{array}
\right].
$$
The above is  is the $R$ part of the QR-factorization.

If $A$ is a larger matrix, we ignore the first two rows and the first two columns and repeat the same procedure.

Comment: I found that in many answers that the first entry of x is just equal to the second and third entries of the second column of $H_1A$. Is that just a coincidence or?

Comment: Your observation is probably a coincidence.  If you get this in every experiment (rather than in many answers), it should be investigated.