# For given column vectors $x$, $y$ how to find an orthogonal matrix $Q$ such that $Qx=y$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices

**Problem**: Given $x=[1,7,2,3,-1]^T $and $y=[-4,4,4,0,-4]^T$, find an orthogonal matrix $Q$ such that $Qx=y$.

**My attempt**: I know the definition of an orthogonal matrix. By definition, if $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix then $Q^{-1}=Q^T$. Further, I know if system of equations $Ax=b$ where $A$ is square matrix, has a solution if $b$ is in column space of $A$ i.e. if $rank(A:b)=rank(A)$.

I didn't able to solve above problem :-( please help me.

Comment: Look up Householder reflection.

Comment: Sir, I didn't know the notion of  the Householder reflection. Can't we solve directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you let $v=\frac{x-y}{\mid\mid y-x\mid\mid}$.

$A=I-2vv^t$ should do the trick.

This is called the Householder reflection.

Comment: Sir thanks for your answer. Sir your answer shows such matrix exists. but, Why such a matrix exists? and how we know when it doesn't exist?

Comment: Note that the two vectors have the same norm.

Comment: This shows that it works:https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1903322