# how can I find a orthogonal matrix Q such that Q$x_i=y_i$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-norms

How can I find a orthogonal matrix Q such that Q$x_i=y_i$ given that $\|x_i\|=\|y_i\|$ and $\|x_i-x_j\|= \|y_i-y_j\|$.
I know that Householder reflectors would do the trick here Q=$I-2pp^T$ where p is ($x_i-y_i$)/$\|x_i-y_i\|$.  but I am unable to understand how can someone please explain this to me.

Here $x_i , y_i \in R^n$

I also read this [Rotation by Householder matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1903312/841957) solution but couldn't understand the how part.

Comment: Are you doing this for one value of $i$ or for $n$ values of $i$?

Comment: @TedShifrin for n values of i and all $x_i$ are independent vectors

Comment: What more do you know about the vectors $x_i$ and about the vectors $y_i$? For example, are the $x_i$ all mutually orthogonal and same for the $y_i$?  You need more geometric conditions.

Comment: Independence is a good start, but unless you know that the angles between the $x_i$ match up to the angles between the $y_i$, you won't be able to get an orthogonal $Q$.

Comment: i'm provided with only 2 conditions which are 

$\|x_i\|_2=\|y_i\|_2$ and $\|x_i-x_j\|_2= \|y_i-y_j\|_2$.

Comment: Well, that is an additional geometric condition, isn't it? I'm a little troubled, though, if the $x_i$ all have different lengths. Are all the $\|x_i\|$ the same?

Comment: No, $x_1, x_2.................x_n \in R^n$ are n independent vectors and  $y_1,y_2...............y_n$ are vectors such that $\|x_i\|= \|y_i\|$ and  $\|x_i-x_j\|_2= \|y_i-y_j\|_2$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120834/discussion-between-milf-hunter-and-ted-shifrin).

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible with more than 2 vectors, but I haven’t worked it out.

Comment: @Ted, my impression is that we are given two conguent simplices, for $n=2$ congruent triangles with shared vertex at the origin

Comment: right, $n=3$ would be congruent tetrahedra common vertex at origin. The part that need not influence calculations amounts to the proof that an isometry that fixes the origin in Euclidean space is linear

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, of course, you're right. So we just observe that the (unique) matrix that takes $x_i$ to $y_i$ (i.e., $Q=AB^{-1}$ where the columns of $A$ are the $y_i$ and the columns of $B$ are the $x_i$) is in fact an isometry and hence orthogonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Householder reflection gives you a reflection across the hyperplane orthogonal to the unit vector $p$ (note that $pp^\top$ gives projection onto the line spanned by $p$, and so subtracting twice that leaves the hyperplane orthogonal to $p$ fixed and reflects across that hyperplane). That said, if you do a Householder reflection as you suggested with $p=\dfrac{x_i-y_i}{\|x_i-y_i\|}$, it switches $x_i$ and $y_i$ and leaves the hyperplane orthogonal to $x_i-y_i$ fixed. If the remaining $x_j$ and $y_j$ are not in that hyperplane, they will be messed up by this reflection. Thus, I don't see any good way to use this repeatedly with more vectors.

However, as Will Jagy pushed me to realize, the solution is easy. Let $A$ be the matrix whose columns are the $y_i$ and let $B$ be the matrix whose columns are the $x_i$. Observe that when we set $Q=AB^{-1}$, it will have property that $Qx_i = y_i$ for all $i$. The easiest way to see this is the following: If $e_j$ are the standard basis for $\Bbb R^n$, then by construction we have $Be_i=x_i$ and $Ae_i = y_i$. Therefore, $(AB^{-1})x_i = A(B^{-1}x_i) = Ae_i = y_i$, as required. Finally, as Will pointed out, the geometric hypotheses tell us that the $n$-dimensional pyramids formed by the $x_i$ and by the $y_i$ are congruent, and so $Q$ must be an isometry of $\Bbb R^n$. By a standard argument, $Q$ must be linear and, indeed, an orthogonal matrix. (For a proof, see, for example, pp. 114-115 of [my differential geometry text](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the vectors $x_i$ form a basis, let $Q$ be the unique linear transformation that maps $x_i$ to $y_i$.

We need to show that $Q$ is orthogonal, that is, respects the inner product.
But, by hypothesis the inner product of basis elements are preserved because if $i\ne j$
$$\langle x_i,x_j\rangle=-\frac12\big(\|x_i-x_j\|^2-\|x_i\|^2-\|x_j\|^2\big)\,.$$
if $i\ne j$.

If the given vectors $x_i$ are only linearly independent, then we can extend them, say by an orthonormal basis of $\big({\rm span}(x_i)_i\big)^\perp$ and similarly extend $y_i$ by an orthonormal basis of $\big({\rm span}(y_i)_i\big)^\perp$.