# Given $\|x_1\|=\|x_2\|$, then there is an orthogonal matrix $\Gamma$ such that $x_2=\Gamma x_1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, orthonormal, orthogonal-matrices

Let $x_1, x_2$ be members of $\mathbb R^p$ such that $\|x_1\|=\|x_2\|$. Then there is an orthogonal matrix $\Gamma$ such that $x_2=\Gamma x_1$.

How to prove the above? I know given $x_2=\Gamma x_1$, since any orthogonal matrix preserves the length of the vector, thus $\|x_1\|=\|x_2\|$. But I don't know how to prove the converse direction?

Comment: Perhaps first consider the easier case $x_1=e_1$

Comment: Think about orthonormal bases.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1903322/81360) for one approach

Comment: If $x_1\neq 0$, then we can reduce to the case $\Vert x_1\Vert=1$ (otherwise consider $x_1/\Vert x_1\Vert$ and $x_2/\Vert x_2\Vert$). Then construct an orthogonal basis containing $x_1$ and another orthogonal basis containing $x_2$. Then map those bases to each other in a suitable fashion.

Comment: @Jonathen Given the vector $p$, the matrix $P$ you're looking for is $I - 2pp^T$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Excellent! The last question is how to see this matrix $I-2pp^T$ is orthogonal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reflection through the hyperplane orthogonal to $x_1 - x_2$ and passing through the origin maps $x_1 \mapsto x_2$ and $x_2 \mapsto x_1$. This reflection can be written
$$
  \Gamma x = x - 2(x_1-x_2)\frac{(x_1-x_2)^Tx}{||x_1-x_2||^2}
$$
implying that
$$
  \Gamma = I - 2\frac{(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_2)^T}{||x_1-x_2||^2},
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix, is the orthogonal matrix you seek.

(In the case $x_1 = x_2$ we can just take $\Gamma = I$.)

The hypothesis $||x_1|| = ||x_2||$ is crucial otherwise this reflection does not swap $x_1$ and $x_2$. You should think hard *geometrically* about how $x_1$ gets mapped to $x_2$ given that $\Gamma$ is a reflection in the way that I described. To see how it happens algebraically, first note that
$$
  -2x_2^Tx_1 = ||x_1-x_2||^2 - ||x_1||^2 - ||x_2||^2.
$$
Then
$$
  2\frac{(x_1-x_2)^Tx_1}{||x_1-x_2||^2} = \frac{2||x_1||^2 + ||x_1-x_2||^2 - ||x_1||^2 - ||x_2||^2}{||x_1-x_2||^2} = 1
$$
using the hypothesis $||x_1|| = ||x_2||$ in the last equality. Now we see that
$$
  \Gamma x_1 = x_1 - (x_1 - x_2) = x_2.
$$
Because $\Gamma$ is symmetric in $x_1, x_2$ this also proves that $\Gamma x_2 = x_1$.

Comment: How to see $\Gamma x_1=x_2$?

Comment: The hyperplane has to pass through $\frac12(x_1+x_2)$. One should include this in the discussion. In general this will be an affine transformation, but here it is in fact linear.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm not entirely sure what you mean. If you mean that I should mention that the hyperplane has to pass through the origin, I think I usually assume so implicitly and clarify only when they don't pass through the origin, but I can add that.

Comment: Ordinarily the reflection switching the points is through a hyperplane *not* passing through the origin.  I think it’s critical to explain why this one does pass through the origin.

Comment: @TedShifrin Fair enough, I will add something when I can.

Comment: @Jonathen See my edit.

Comment: How to see $\Gamma$ is an orthogonal matrix?

Comment: @Jonathen A matrix is orthogonal iff it is the matrlx of an orthogonal transformation expressed in the standard basis. An *orthogonal transformation* is a linear transformation $T : \mathbb R^p \to \mathbb R^p$ which preserves the standard inner product, i.e. $(Ta)\cdot(Tb) = a\cdot b$ for all vectors $a,b$, and this is equivalent to $||Ta|| = ||a||$ for all $a$. So if you understand that $\Gamma$ is a reflection, and that reflections preserve lengths, then it is automatic that $\Gamma$ is orthogonal.

Comment: Alternatively, compute $\Gamma^T\Gamma$; you will find that it is $I$, and this is exactly the definition of an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: Can you explain that "The reflection through the hyperplane orthogonal to $x_1 - x_2$ and passing through the origin maps $x_1 \mapsto x_2$ and $x_2 \mapsto x_1$. "? Basically my question is where the idea of this orthogonal matrix come from?

Answer (score 2):

If either vector is the zero vector, then they both are (why?) and this is trivial (how?). Now, assuming that $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^p$ satisfy $\|x_1\| = \|x_2\| \neq 0$, consider their normalized versions
$$
y_1 = \frac{x_1}{\|x_1\|} 
\quad\text{and}\quad
y_2 = \frac{x_2}{\|x_2\|}. 
$$

Using the Gram–Schmidt algorithm$^\dagger\!$, we can complete $y_1$ to an orthonormal basis $\mathcal{B}_1 = \{ y_1, u_2, \dots u_p \}$, and similarly we can complete $y_2$ to an orthonormal basis $\mathcal{B}_2 = \{ y_2, v_2, \dots v_p \}$. Also, let $\mathcal{E} = \{ e_1, \dots e_p \}$ denote the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^p$.

Now, let $P_1$ denote the matrix with vectors from $\mathcal{B}_1$ as columns, and analogously for $P_2$ with vectors from $\mathcal{B}_2$. By construction, both $P_1$ and $P_2$ are orthogonal matrices. And since $P_1 e_1 = y_1$ and $P_2 e_1 = y_2$, the matrix
$$
P = P_2^{\phantom{1}} P_1^{-1}
$$
satisfies $P y_1 = y_2$.

Now, we can check that $P$ does the job for the original vectors as well:
$$
Px_1 = P \bigl( \|x_1\| \, y_1 \bigr)
= \|x_1\| \, P \bigl( y_1 \bigr) 
= \|x_2\| \, y_2 
= x_2.
$$

Note: this same idea gives a stronger result. Namely, given any pair of orthogonal bases whose corresponding vectors have same length, there's an orthogonal (orthonormal) matrix that simultaneously maps each vector in the first basis to the corresponding vector in the second basis.

---

$^\dagger$Generically, this clearly works by just forming the basis $\{ y_1, e_2, \dots, e_p \}$ then applying G–S. I leave it to you to check the edge cases where $y_1 \in \operatorname{span} \{ e_1, \dots, e_i \}$ for some $1 \leq i < p$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the plane defined by $x_1$ and $x_2$.  You can rotate $x_1$ in this plane until it is aligned with $x_2$.  A rotation is an orthogonal transformation.